# Check for empty cellsl of a currentrow in DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net

How can I check a CurrentRow cell whether have data or not and it any cell has not data then a MessageBox come up to warn that select a non null cell. If not below code occur error as "Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted."

```
Private Sub MerhabaToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MerhabaToolStripMenuItem.Click
    DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub MerhabaToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MerhabaToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If Not DataGridView1.CurrentRow.IsNewRow Then
         DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
    End If
End Sub
```